# Configuring Unity to resolve a type that takes a decorated dependency that has a parameter that varies with the type into which it is injected

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

This is a fairly straight forward decorator pattern scenario, with the complication that the decorated type has a constructor parameter that is dependent on the type into which it is being injected.

I have an interface like this:

```
interface IThing
{
    void Do();
}
```

And an implementation like this:

```
class RealThing : IThing
{
    public RealThing(string configuration)
    {
        ... implementation ...
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        ... implementation ...
    }
}
```

And a decorator like this:

```
class DecoratingThing : IThing
{
    IThing _innerThing;

    public DecoratingThing(IThing thing)
    {
        _innerThing = thing;    
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        _innerThing.Do();
    }
}
```

Finally, I have some types that require an `IThing`, called `Depender1`, `Depender2` etc..

```
class DependerX()
{
    public DependerX(IThing thing)
    {
        ... implementation ...
    }
}
```

I want to configure an IOC container to resolve instances of `DependerX` such that they are injected with `RealThing` decorated with a `DecoratingThing`. **Important:** Each `DependerX` **type** requires a different value of `configuration` to be passed to the constructor of its `RealThing`, say "ConfigX" in each case. e.g. The work done by the IoC container might be:

```
new Depender1(new DecoratingThing(new RealThing("Config1")));
new Depender2(new DecoratingThing(new RealThing("Config2")));
```

... and so on.

In Unity, this seems quite clunky to configure as I have to mix in the decorator with the decorated:

```
container.RegisterType<IThing, DecoratingThing>("ConfigX",
    new InjectionFactory(container => new DecoratingThing(new RealThing("ConfigX"));

container.RegisterType<DependerX>(
    new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IThing>("ConfigX");
```

And repeat, violating DRY nicely, for each `DependerX`.

What I'd like to do is remove the need to embed the construction of `RealThing` in the construction of `DecoratingThing` in each named registration of `IThing` - and declare the decoration just once. This is so, for example, that if the decoration needs to change in future, it's easier to reconfigure. The best I came up with is this helper method for registration:

```
void RegisterDepender<TDepender>(IUnityContainer container, string config)
{
    container.RegisterType<TDepender>(new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<IThing>(config)));
    container.RegisterType<IThing, DecoratingThing>(config,
        new InjectionFactory(c => new DecoratingThing(new RealThing(config))));
}
```

This removes repetition at least, but I still have to embed the construction of the `RealThing` inside the `DecoratingThing` - this means I can't vary their lifetimes independently for example. I can't register `IThing` again to do this because I've used up my registration of that interface for the name. If I want to do that I have to introduce another set of named instances like so:

```
void RegisterDepender<TDepender>(IUnityContainer container, string config)
{
    string realConfig = "Real" + config;

    container.RegisterType<TDepender>(new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<IThing>(config)));
    container.RegisterType<IThing, DecoratingThing>(config,
        new InjectionFactory(c => new DecoratingThing(
            container.Resolve<IThing>(realConfig))));
    container.RegisterType<IThing, RealThing>(realConfig,
        new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
        new InjectionConstructor(config));
}
```

Is this *really* the best option? It feels complex and potentially hard for those that will come after to grok. Do other IoC containers have a compelling way to cover this scenario? Since the pattern for how injection works is repeated for each DependerX, is there a way to only use a named instance at the top (`DependerX`) level?

Any other comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class design itself seems reasonable. Here's a **convention-based** container configuration that basically does this:

```
public class MyConventions : UnityContainerExtension
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        var dependers = from t in typeof(IThing).Assembly.GetExportedTypes()
                        where t.Name.StartsWith("Depender")
                        select t;

        foreach (var t in dependers)
        {
            var number = t.Name.TrimStart("Depender".ToArray());
            var realName = "Real" + number;
            var decoName = "Deco" + number;
            var config = "Config" + number;
            this.Container.RegisterType<IThing, RealThing>(realName, 
                new InjectionConstructor(config));
            this.Container.RegisterType<IThing, DecoratingThing>(decoName,
                new InjectionConstructor(
                    new ResolvedParameter<IThing>(realName)));
            this.Container.RegisterType(t,
                new InjectionConstructor(
                    new ResolvedParameter<IThing>(decoName)));
        }
    }
}
```

This configuration will automatically add all classes that match the above predicate, so once you've set it up, you can just add more classes (like `Depender4` or `Depender5`) without revisiting the container configuration at all.

The above configuration satisfies these unit tests:

```
[Fact]
public void ContainerCorrectlyResolvesDepender1()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer().AddNewExtension<MyConventions>();
    var actual = container.Resolve<Depender1>();

    var deco = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<DecoratingThing>(actual.Thing);
    var thing = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<RealThing>(deco.Thing);
    Assert.Equal("Config1", thing.Configuration);
}

[Fact]
public void ContainerCorrectlyResolvesDepender2()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer().AddNewExtension<MyConventions>();
    var actual = container.Resolve<Depender2>();

    var deco = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<DecoratingThing>(actual.Thing);
    var thing = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<RealThing>(deco.Thing);
    Assert.Equal("Config2", thing.Configuration);
}

[Fact]
public void ContainerCorrectlyResolvesDepender3()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer().AddNewExtension<MyConventions>();
    var actual = container.Resolve<Depender3>();

    var deco = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<DecoratingThing>(actual.Thing);
    var thing = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<RealThing>(deco.Thing);
    Assert.Equal("Config3", thing.Configuration);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. I think a convention based approach is the way to go in my particular scenario. That's not to say that other approaches (such as the interception idea above) aren't equally valid. It's good to hear I'm not way off the beaten track here!

Answer (score 3):

Have you ever thought about basing your decorators on the Unity Interception functionality? Then it would be really easy to say "intercept the calls to `IThing` using this Interceptor" just once.

```
container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
container.RegisterType<IThing>(new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), new InterceptionBehavior<DecoratingThingBehavior>());
```

and then it would be "inject this `IThing` into this and that `Depender`"

```
container.RegisterType<Depender1>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IThing>("myNameForThing")));
```

Comment: I view this as a different approach to decoration rather than an implemenation of it. I have thought about it and I think in this particular case I'm not really dealing with a suitable cross-cutting concern. It's quite specific in scope and the behaviour of the decorator is dependent on the method being called. I think in this case I'd probably shifting the complexity into the logic of the interception. The decorator I have is pre-existing, quite complex and used elsewhere so refactoring is non-trivial. Given the information in the question though, it's a great suggestion so I am giving it +1.