# Solving multiple interface implementation

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, interface, unity-container

I am in this situation where my service interface is being implemented by two service classes.

For example,

**`IFooService`** is implemented by **`FooService`** and **`FooWithExtraInfoService`**

Here is the interface:

```
public interface IFooService
{
    Foo GetEntity(string fieldName, stringFieldValue);
}
```

Here is **`FooService`**:

```
public class FooService: BarService,  IFooService
{
    public FooService(ILogService logservice): base(logservice)
    {
    }

    public Foo GetEntity(string fieldName, string fieldValue)
    {
        //here goes the logic
    }
}
```

Here is **`FooWithExtraInfoService`**:

```
public class FooWithExtraInfoService: BarService, IFooService
{
    public FooWithExtraInfoService(ILogService logservice): base(logservice)
    {
    }

    public Foo GetEntity(string fieldName, string fieldValue)
    {
        //one possible option could be
        var foo = new FooService(logservice).GetEntity(fieldName, fieldValue)
        //do additional stuff
        foo.SomeField = "abc";
    }
}
```

As you can see one option could be creating new object of FooService and then telling unity to register type where `IFooService` is implemented by `FooWithExtraInfoService`.

Something like:

```
container.RegisterType<IFooService, FooWithExtraInfoService>();
```

But is there some other way where I don't have to create new object of `FooService`?

```
//one possible option could be
var fooService = new FooService(logservice).GetEntity(fieldName, fieldValue)
//do additional stuff
```

And let Unity handle it somehow?

Or should I create different interface for `FooWithExtraInfoService`?

I don't know what is the best way to approach this problem at this point.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good candidate for the [decorator pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator).

The decorator pattern wraps the existing service, adding additional functionality to it without having to *make changes* to it. This allows you to cleanly separate responsibilities of what `FooService` does from `FooWithExtraInfoService` and still allow the DI container to provide the "inner" instance.

```
public class FooWithExtraInfoService : IFooService
{
    private readonly IFooService fooService;

    public FooWithExtraInfoService(IFooService fooService)
    {
        if (fooService == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fooService));
        this.fooService = fooService;
    }

    public Foo GetEntity(string fieldName, string fieldValue)
    {
        // call the decorated instance of IFooService
        var foo = this.fooService.GetEntity(fieldName, fieldValue);
        //do additional stuff
        foo.SomeField = "abc";
    }
}
```

Then you just need to wire it up with your DI container like:

```
var instance = new FooWithExtraInfoService(new FooService(new LogService()));
```

In Unity, this registration could be done like:

```
container.RegisterType<ILogService, LogService>();

// Register FooService as a named service
container.RegisterType<IFooService, FooService>("foo");

// Register FooWithExtraInfoService and inject FooService into it
container.RegisterType<IFooService, FooWithExtraInfoService>(
    new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IFooService>("foo")));
```

> **NOTE:** An example of how you could make decorator registrations convention-based is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9017960).

Unlike using inheritance, the decorator is **loosely coupled** from `FooService`. The `ILogService` does not need to be passed into the decorator only so it can be forwarded into the superclass constructor. Additionally, you can easily add another decorator class between `FooWithExtraInfoService` and `FooService` simply by changing the DI configuration.

```
var instance = new FooWithExtraInfoService(
    new FooDecorator1(
    new FooService(new Logger())));
```

Comment: I like this answer till now, unless someone comes up with better answer in a while. I will accept this answer. But my confusion is Unity injection, I saw the link to the answer you posted and for me it was little complicated. Could you in simple terms post here and update the answer, I think this might help other people too

Comment: I have updated the answer to include the simplest Unity decorator registration.

Comment: If you pass the decorated type as type parameter, registration becomes simple, without the need to resolve at registration time. See this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18748399/5758420

Comment: That seems to defeat the purpose of using a decorator. But then, Unity really sucks at this sort of thing - most other DI containers have a way to inject specific parameters without having to define the whole constructor signature.

Answer (score 0):

Given both inherit from `BarService`, create an intermediate type `FooServiceBase` that implements the interface:

```
public abstract class FooServiceBase : BarService, IFooService
{
    public Foo GetEntity(string fieldName, string fieldValue)
    {
        //here goes the logic
    }
}
```

And let `FooWithExtraInfoService` and `FooService` inherit from that.

Comment: How would that help anyway? Problem is with DI here?

Comment: @Rahul as far as I understand, the problem is with "traits", or letting two types who implement the same interface implement the same behavior.

Comment: My FooWithExtraInfoService has to use the GetEntity method of FooService and after GettingEntity FooWithExtraInfoService will add other stuffs to that entity

Comment: So you are essentially saying this `container.RegisterType<IFooService, FooServiceBase >();`

Comment: @Cybercop so then you make it virtual, override it and call the base implementation.

Comment: so when I use the IFooService how will Unity know which service to use as implementation?

Comment: @Cybercop it doesn't. Is your problem about a duplicate implementation of the same interface method, or is it about registering two services for the same interface? Because those are vastly different problems, and your question edges on the first.

Comment: problem is two services are implementing same interface but one implementation should use other implentation and extend it. I don't know if having seperate interface would be good as they both are returning same entity (one will have more information)

Comment: I don't even know if this approach is good and if I need to have seperate interfaces for this implementations

Answer (score 0):

I believe in your case you should use `Composition` ... mean have a property of type `FooService` rather like below since you just want to use the `GetEntity()` method and have no intention of extending it

```
public class FooWithExtraInfoService: BarService
{
   public FooService FooService { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you can't always rely on the interface alone to define the behavior your service-consumers require, one alternative is to register one or both of your concrete implementations for DI.

Then any class that can safely depend on the simpler `IFooService` can declare a dependency on that, and those which you know will need the additional capabilites from `FooWithExtraInfoService` can depend upon that instead. And `FooWithExtraInfoService` can even declare a dependency on `IFooService` to inject the simpler implementation.

Basically, interface services are useful, but don't get too hung up on trying to use them in every case.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the `FooWithExtraInfoService` is meant to be `FooService`, but with extra info, right?

So then, actually *make* it a `FooService` class with extra info. Give the `GetEntity` function in `FooService` the `virtual` keyword, and it can be overridden in child classes. This then allows you to have a new override in `FooWithExtraInfoService` which can simply call its parent implementation.

The adapted `FooService` class:

```
public class FooService: BarService,  IFooService
{
    public FooService(ILogService logservice): base(logservice)
    {
    }

    public virtual Foo GetEntity(string fieldName, string fieldValue)
    {
        //here goes the logic
    }
}
```

The implementation:

```
public class FooWithExtraInfoService: FooService
{
    public FooWithExtraInfoService(ILogService logservice): base(logservice)
    {
    }

    public override Foo GetEntity(string fieldName, string fieldValue)
    {
        Foo foo = base.GetEntity(fieldName, fieldValue)
        //do additional stuff
        foo.SomeField = "abc";
    }
}
```